# Is it posiblie to open 2 or more SP list views in one excel book?

Tags: javascript, excel, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have some js code that that makes a button export 2 views to excel (from the main view).
When i click the button everything works fine but it opens the files one at a time and after i open the first file i get a pop-up thats generated from excel (see the pic).
I've been trying to find a function that would do what that pop-up does. I'm trying to have both views open in the same workbook. Is it possible?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fDaN2.png]

Js code..

```
<script type="text/javascript">         
        function itsa()
        {
            window.open("http://*********/***/*******/******/_vti_bin/owssvr.dll?CS=109&Using=_layouts/query.iqy&List={******************************&View={***************************}&CacheControl=1");
        }

        function other()
        {
             window.open("http://*********/***/*******/******/_vti_bin/owssvr.dll?CS=109&Using=_layouts/query.iqy&List={******************************}&View={******************************}&CacheControl=1");
        }

        </script>


        <div class="wrapper">
            <input type="button" style="width:180px; height: 75px; background:gray; color:white;font-size:larger; font-weight:bold; left: 214px;"onclick="itsa();other();" value ="Generate Excel report"/>


        </div>
```

Comment: You would need to get an instance of the open workbook in order to load your results into it -- I'm sure it's possible but it would probably on work in IE and may be more trouble than it's worth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to answer my own question..

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        function itsa() 
        {
            window.open("http://*********/***/*******/******/_vti_bin/owssvr.dll?CS=109&Using=_layouts/query.iqy&List={******************************}&View={******************************}&CacheControl=1");
        }

        function other() 
        {
             window.open("http://*********/***/*******/******/_vti_bin/owssvr.dll?CS=109&Using=_layouts/query.iqy&List={******************************}&View={******************************}&CacheControl=1");
        }

        </script>


        <div class="wrapper">
            <input type="button" style="width:180px; height: 75px; background:gray; color:white;font-size:larger; font-weight:bold; left: 214px;"onclick="itsa();other();" value ="Generate Excel report"/> 
        </div>
```

And then click on "Existing Worksheet" when it pop's up.